# Why does three same activity behave differently to the same function?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider, android-context, android-side-navigation

I have three `DrawerLayout` for three `Activity`. These activities are mostly same (layouts are copy past). Let's call them as `activity 1`, `activity 2`, `activity 3`. `activity 1` can start `activity 2`, `activity 2` can start `activity 3`.

Besides I have my custom base activity: `SideMenuActivity`.

They are all extends `SideMenuActivity`.

There is a button to open a navigation drawer, whose `onClickListener` is in `SideMenuActivity`:

```
    protected void initSideMenu() {
        sideMenuButton = findViewById(R.id.side_menu_icon_clickable);
        sideMenu = findViewById(R.id.side_menu);
        sideMenu.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        .
        .
        .
        sideMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sideMenuButton.startAnimation(buttonClick);
                sideMenu.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getClass().getSimpleName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I call this function from both 'activity 1', `activity 2` and `activity 3`. Navigation drawer can be opened in `activity 1` and `activity 2` but not in `activity 3`.

Why does this `onClickListener` not work in `activity 3`. Does android have a bug or what?

Also the toast message doesn't appear in `activity 3` unlike the others.

Here is the `DrawerLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/side_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/menucontent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/appMainBackground"
        tools:context=".xxx.xxx.xxx">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include2"
            layout="@layout/topbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline17"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1184" />

        .
        .
        .

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: "Why does this onClickListener not work in activity 3" what does `not work` mean ?

Comment: activity 3 cannot execute lines of this onClickListener

Comment: Try using Layout Inspector https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector to figure out that if your drawer is getting layed out or not in actiivty 3.

Comment: I think problem is not about that because the Toast message is not appearing unlike other activities @mdb. It's about button's OnClickListener.